# Increasing in each point implies increasing.

Tags: real-analysis

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$ Let $f: \R \to \R$ be a function. We say $f$ is increasing in $p \in \R$ iff  $\exists \delta > 0 : x \in (p-\delta,p), y \in (p,p+\delta) \Rightarrow f(x) \leq f(p) \leq f(y)$. We say $f$ is increasing if $f(a) \leq f(b)$ if $a \leq b$.

> If $f$ is increasing in each point $p \in \R$ then $f$ is increasing.

I tried to do this as follows: Assume $f(a) > f(b)$ for some $a < b$ in $\R$. Let $c := \frac{a+b} 2$. Then $f(a) > f(c)$ of $f(c) > f(b)$. In the first case let $a_1 := a$ and $b_1 := c$ and in the second case let $a_1 := c$ and $b_1 := b$. Now proceed like this. This gives intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ s.t. $f(a_n) > f(b_n)$ and $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]\subseteq [a_n,b_n]$. Since all intervals are non empty and compact and decreasing the intersection is non empty. So let $x \in \cap_n [a_n,b_n]$. I think that $f$ is not increasing in $x$ but I can't show it. Please help !

Comment: Probably $\forall x \in (p - \delta, p), \cdots$?

Comment: One can even say that $\bigcap[a_n,b_n]$ is exactly one point $x$.

Comment: Couldn't you assume a $δ$ such that [second line of your post] and then consider the interval $[a_k,b_k]\subset(x-δ,x+δ)$ ?

Comment: Sorry for the typo(s).

Comment: For each $p$ in the interval $[a,b]$, let $U_p$ be an interval of the type guaranteed by "increasing at $p$." This is an open cover, so has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is locally increasing at $x$, then there is a $δ$ such that $f(u)\le f(x)\le f(v)$ for all $x-δ<u\le x\le v<x+δ$. On the other hand, there is a $k\in N$ such that $[a_k,b_k]\subset(x-δ,x+δ)$. We have $f(a_k)>f(b_k)$. But $x-δ<a_k\le x\le b_k<x+δ$, so $f(a_k)\le f(b_k)$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @André: Please also upvote my answer if it was useful :-)